# How to transfer GET values from URL from PAGE1 to a JSON webservice with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I'm trying to create a kind of searcher for a webpage. In the first page, the user must fill a form, wich send the values to Page1. Then, page1 is loaded and page1 "ask" to a webservice using the same values which it received from the form.

In other words, what I need is:
pass the GET values from PAGE1 to a JSON Webservice with javascript/jQuery

---

Example:

Page1:

```
 www.example.com/page1.php?parameter1=qqq&parameter2=yyyy&parameter3=ppp......
```

Page 1 must call a webservice with:

```
www.example.com/webservice.php?parameter1=qqq&parameter2=yyyy&parameter3=ppp......
```

Then the webservice return some values, and that values are used in Page1.php

In page one, i'm using the following code to read the webservice:

```
$.getJSON("domain.com/getpublicaciones.php?", {
//HERE I HAVE TO USE THE GET PAIR OF VALUES: paramter1:qqq, paramter2=yyy and so on.
latitud: "11.223324",
longitud: "12.345343"
},function(data) {
for (i=0; i<data.posts.length; i++) {}
}
```

Comment: look into [php _POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, the var "parametros" has all the values passed in the URL.
Example:
domain.com/page1.php?parameter1=qqq&parameter2=ppp...

You can see use the value in this way:
     alert(parametros.parameter1)    ---> Has "qqq"
     alert(parametros.parameter2)    ---> Has "ppp"

Finally I solved it with the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //The var "parametros" has all the parameters passed throught GET in the URL.
    parametros=getURLParameters();
    $.getJSON("http://domain.com/getpublicaciones.php?", parametros,function(data){
       for (i=0; i<data.posts.length; i++) {
          var array_sucursal = data.posts[i];
       }


function getURLParameters(){
    var rv = {},s=[];
    var gets = location.href.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[^&]+/g);
    if (gets){
        var l = gets.length; 
        for(var i =0; i<l; i++){
            s = gets[i].split('='); 
            rv[s[0]]=s[1];
        }
    }
    return rv; 
}
```